# Frame environment in a file called by \input doesn´t work properly

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer, input

The example below works fine, but if I put the frame environment inside the file matrix.tex that \input calls than I get an error message and the file doesn't compile.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix,shapes,arrows,calc}

\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usetheme{CambridgeUS}


\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{example}
        \input{matrix}    
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

The file matrix.tex:

```
\begin{adjustbox}{max totalsize={.99\textheight},center}    

\begin{tikzpicture}[>=stealth',shorten >=1pt,auto,node distance=4 and 6, semithick]


\matrix(m) [matrix of math nodes, nodes in empty cells, nodes={minimum size=.7cm, outer sep=0pt, text height=1.0ex, text depth=.25ex}]
{
   9 &    &     & 8 &   &     &  12    &    &   & 13 &    &  &    &   &    &    &     \\
     &    &     &   &   &     &        &    &   &    &    &  &    &   &    &    &     \\
     &    & 1   &   &   &  2  &        &    & 7 &    &    & 1&    &   &    &    &     \\
 10  &    &     & 10&   &     &  12    &    &   & 14 &    &  &    &   &    &    &     \\
     &    &     &   &   &     &        &    &   &    &    &  &    &   &    &    &     \\
     &    &  2  &   &   & 1   &        &    & 2 &    &    &2 &    &   &    &    &     \\
     };


\draw [blue] (m-1-1.north west) rectangle (m-6-12.south east);

% Lineas horizontales
\foreach \i in {3} {
  \draw[blue] (m-\i-1.south west) -- (m-\i-12.south east);
}

% Lineas verticales
\foreach \j in {3,6,9} {
  \draw[blue] (m-1-\j.north east) -- (m-6-\j.south east);
}


\foreach \i in {3,6} {
    \foreach \j in {3,6,9,12} {
            \draw[blue] (m-\i-\j.south west) rectangle (m-\i-\j.north east);
    }
}


\end{tikzpicture}

\end{adjustbox}
```

Comment: I am able to compile the MWE without errors, with lualatex and pdflatex, as expected. The `\input` only puts the code of the other file in place. The error you mentioned happens with THIS code or with other?

Comment: It happens when I put  ```\begin{document}

        \input{matrix}    

\end{document}``` and the ```\begin{frame}``` and ```\end{frame}``` is inside the file that I call.  It should be the same as you say, but it doesn`t work.

Comment: Please correct your MWE